# different third party dll's have minimum requirement of different versions of same dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

Question Title is probably too complicated.

I will explain. I have in my project Referred Mailchimp.Net which requires System.Net.Http (4.1.1) Version. This works well.

But now I need to add another third party dll which unfortunately depends on 4.0.0 version of System.Net.Http and if i add it, it doesnt work, because well it searches for 4.0.0 which doesn't exist as I have higher version referenced.

However If I refer lower version then Mail chimp won't work.

This is weird but is there a good solution to this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Comment: I think question I linked as duplicate provides all information you looking for for this very common problem. If not enough - see MSDN (including linked from duplicate and one provided by @ScottChamberlain), search - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+assembly+binding+redirect and then [edit] question to clarify why your case is different. Side note: I'm not sure what you refer to as "this is weird" as problem you've described happens all the time to pretty much anyone using any shared library with Json.Net one being most common one as a lot of other libraries rely on it.